# Java Interface implementation problem

Tags: java, interface

I have problem with sets. Required java.lang.String found String... 
What can i do there?

```
public interface Node {
        public <V> V get();
        public <V> void sets(V value);
    }

public enum MIBNodes implements Node {

    TEST {
         private String e;
        @Override
        public String get() {
            return "aa";
        }

        @Override
        public <String> void sets(String value) {
           e=value;
        }




    };


};
```

**UPDATE**
Each enum instance like TEST , TEST1 ... may have different type.. String, Integer or anyother... So `public enum MIBNodes implements Node {` cant become `public enum MIBNodes implements Node<String>` {

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the Problem:

```
@Override
public <String> void sets(String value) {
        ^^^^^^
    e=value;
}
```

Here, `String` is a type variable (a re-definition of `V`), not a `java.lang.String`. And I don't really think you can fix that without changing your design:

```
public interface Node<V> {
    public V get();
    public void sets(V value);
}
```

And in case you want your enum to be generic : that's impossible. Different enum items can't implement the same interface with different generic parameters.

Comment: So any alternative solution to this?

Comment: @Parhs One enum per Generic Type, I'm afraid

Comment: Of course it works for get: you can always return a more specific type (and document that in the method signature). But you can't take a more specific parameter than the super class or interface